# Why some part of an os has to be written in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, interrupt, nios

The scheduler of my mini os is written in assembly and I wonder why. I found out that the instruction `eret` can't be generated by the C compiler, is this somthing that can be generalized to other platforms than Nios and also x86 and/or MIPS architechture? Since I believe that part of os is always written in assembly and I'm searching for why a systems programmer must know assembly to write an operating system. Is is the case that there are builtin limitations of the C compiler that can't generate certain assembly instructions like the `eret` that returns the program to what is was doing after an interrupt?

Comment: That's not *really* true.  Options exist for doing it entirely in C, but it can be awkward.  Even if the inline assembler module doesn't support an instruction it's often possible to use an executable string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic answer is for one of three reasons:

1. Because that particular type of code can't be written in C. I think `eret` is a "return from exception" instruction, so there is no C equivalent to this (because hardware exceptions such as page faults, divide by zero or similar are not C/C++ style exceptions). Another example may be saving the registers onto the stack when task-switching, and saving the stack pointer into the task-control block. The C code can't do that, because there is no direct access to the stack pointer.
2. Because the compiler won't produce as good code as someone clever writing assembler. Some specialized operations can be hard to write in C - the compiler may not generate very good code, or the code gets very convoluted to achieve something that is simple in assembler.
3. The startup of C code needs to be written in assembler, because a C program needs certain things set up before you can run actual C code. For example configuring the stack-pointer, and some other registers.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, that is it.  There are instructions that you cannot generate using C language.  And there are usually one or some instructions required for an OS so some assembly is required.  This is true for pretty much any instruction set, x86, arm, mips, and so on.  C compilers let you do inline assembly for jamming instructions in but the language itself cant really handle the nuances of each instruction set and try to account for them.  Some compilers will add compiler specific things to for example return the function using an interrupt flavor of return.  It is so much easier to just write assembly where needed than to customize the language or compilers so there is really no demand there.

Answer (score 3):

The C language expresses the things it is specified to express: fundamental arithmetic operations, assignment of values to variables, and branches and function calls. Objects may be allocated using `static`, automatic (local), or dynamic (malloc) storage duration. If you want something outside this conceptual scope, you need something other than pure C.

The C language can be extended arbitrarily, and many platforms define syntax for things like defining a function or variable at a particular address.

But the hardware of the CPU cares about a lot of details, such as the values of flag registers. The part of the scheduler which switches threads needs to be able to save all the registers to memory before doing anything, because overwriting any register would lose essential data in the interrupted thread.

The only way to be able to write such a thing in C, would be for the compiler to provide a C function which generates the finely-tuned assembly. And then you're essentially back at square 1, because the important details are still at the level of the assembly code.

Vendors with multiple product lines of microcontrollers sometimes go out of their way to allow C source compatibility even at the lowest levels, to allow their customers to port code (or conversely, to prevent them from going to another vendor when they need to switch platforms). But the distinction between C and assembly blurs at a certain point, when you're calling pseudo-functions that generate specific instructions (known as *intrinsics*).

Answer (score 1):

Some things that cannot be done in C or that, if they can be done, are better done in assembly because they are more straightforward and/or maintainable that way include:

- Execute return-from-exception and return-from-interrupt instructions.
- Read from and write to special processor registers (which control processor state, memory mapping, cache configuration, exception management, and more).
- Perform atomic reads and writes to special addresses that are connections to hardware devices rather than memory.
- Perform load and store instructions of particular sizes or characteristics to special addresses as described above. (E.g., writing to a certain devices might require using only a store-16-bits instruction and not a regular store-32-bits instruction.)
- Execute instructions for memory barriers or ordering, cache control, and flushing of memory maps.

Generally, C is mostly designed to do computations (read inputs, calculate things, write outputs) and not to control a machine (interact with all the controls and devices in the machine).